# Wordpress menu that shows all posts in a certain category

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on creating a widget menu(kind of a sidebar like w3schools) that is supposed to show all posts that are listed in a particular category.
 For example from the home page once the user clicks "HTML" in the Nav bar it takes them to the page with introduction about the course and I have put a sidebar custom menu(by using drag and drop) in which there are other posts of the same category by the name of "HTML".

I want to be able to make a post and mark it under "HTML" category, in the menu option I select the menu to show menu only on posts with the "HTML" category and then after that whenever I make a post under the category "HTML", the menu should automatically add another post to the list. Simply put, a dynamic menu that shows all posts under a certain category.

So far I have come across this piece of code but putting it in the editor for menu doesn't work :

```
$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("NameOfTheCategory"));

foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div>
             <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
              <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div> <?php  endforeach;?>
```

I am new to WordPress and I have tried searching everywhere and trying a lot of plugins but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the categories or a specific category using get categories and then run a WP_Query on each category.

```
    //menu loop
function menu_loop() {

global $post;

$args= array(...);
$categories = get_categories( $args);
foreach ($categories as $category ) {

$args = array (...);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();

        }
    }
   // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do I insert this? And in `array(..);` are the dots supposed to be a piece of code or is it that way?

Comment: Also, how do I get a specific category? I mean where do I specify which category I have to get?

Comment: No the dots are not supposed to be a part of the code, go to WordPress codex and read about the arguments you can pass to get_categories function, the same for WP_Query. You can get the above function to get you posts from a category you want by passing a function  parameter through the get_categories() $args

Comment: But how will I then implement them in the custom menu? Sorry I am new to WP

Comment: Just call the function like this menu_loop(); in your sidebar.php file

Comment: So after implementing this whenever I add a new post to the category I want, this will update the menu to include that post, right?

Comment: Exactly! That what happens

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249806/wordpress-dynamic-custom-menu-not-showing-correct-results